# Replacing different text, onClick, to SAME div

Tags: javascript, html

I'm pretty new to javascript and have been at this at awhile, but still can't figure it out, so any advice as how to continue this, would be much appreciated. I've tried to place it in a jsFiddle, but it does not work, even when part of the code is working on my computer. I've got the first part (#preheat and #pans) to do what I want.

javascript:

```
<script>    
    $(function () {   
        $('#preheat').on('click', function () {
            $("<p>Preheat oven to 350°F. Prepare two 9-inch pans by spraying with baking spray.</p>").appendTo('#content');

            $("#steps").replaceWith('<span id="steps1">Allow to <span id="verb_1">cool</span> for about 10 minutes, remove from <span id="noun_1">pans </span>and cool completey.</span>');   
        });


//this part is not working
        $('#cool').on('click', function () {
            $("<p>Allow to cool for about 10 minutes, remove from pans and cool completely.</p>").appendTo('#content');

            $("#steps1").replaceWith('<span id="verb_2">Bake</span><span id="noun_2">chocolate cake</span> for 30-35 minutes, until a toothpick or cake tester inserted in the center comes out clean.'); 
        }); 

        $('#pans').on('click', function () {
            $("<p>Preheat oven to 350°F. Prepare two 9-inch pans by spraying with baking spray.</p>").appendTo('#content');

            $("#steps").replaceWith('<span id="verb1">Distribute</span> cake batter evenly between the <span id="noun1">two cake pans.</span>');
        });    

    });
</script>
```

html:

```
    <div id="steps">
            <span id="preheat">Preheat</span>
            <span>oven to 350°F. Prepare</span>
            <span id="pans">two 9-inch pans</span>
            <span>by spraying with baking spray.</span>
        </div>



    <div id="content">
        <p></p>
   </div>
```

css:

```
 #content{
    float:right;
}
```

Comment: You have an open `span` tag in `#cool` step. `<span id="verb_2"Bake</span>`

Comment: just changed it, still didn't work:(

Comment: with `$('#cool').on('click'` do you mean `$('#steps1').on()`? Or `$('#verb_1')`

Comment: @user3453264 Take a look at this variation of your code - http://jsfiddle.net/a9nUA/ If you click first `Preheat` then you are still able to click `two 9-inch pans` and get the `click` event working. What I think your problem is is that maybe you are not fully aware of how `replaceWith` works.

Comment: You might want to close the '#content' div as well...

Comment: hey guys, thanks for your help. I'm going to try to understand these information, and i'll ask if i've got more qns. Thank you:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#cool').on('click', function () {
```

is not working becauase there is not element with id `cool`.

Also, if you want to delegate a click event for element having id `cool` do

```
$(document).on('click',''#cool', function () { // you can use any valid selector for a parent element of #cool instead of document
```

something like this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/E5L6x/2/) is probably what you need.

Updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/E5L6x/4/)

*side note: at the end of your code, you're trying to replace `#steps` which do not exists any more since you replaced it with something else earlier. You might want to use `html()` function instead  of `replaceWith()` as in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/E5L6x/3/)*

Comment: quick qn: when do i decide to use html() or replaceWith(). sorry i'm really new to this, so i don't really get how java works yet

Comment: If you don't want the element anymore and it needs to be removed from your html use `replaceWith`, if you need it in future use `html()`,

Comment: so it is working, but not really doing what i need. With the first sentence"Preheat..." it is specific such that only when you click the word preheat then it works, but for the sentence "Allow to cool..." it works if you just click the sentence, no longer text specific. How should i tweak it?

Comment: i needed it to work the other way around. LOL for it to be text specific. The updated version is doing the opposite of what i need

Comment: I tried replacing with  
$(document).on('click','#steps1', function () { 
with 
$('#verb_1').on('click', '#steps1', function ()
but still not working

Comment: yup. thank you, now i need to analyse it. LOL thank you so much